# Node js 14 for alpine in Docker

Tags: php, node.js, docker, alpine-linux

One of my old laravel vue with docker project I updated php:8.2-fpm-alpine but I need old node 14 how can I get

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

ARG SERVER_ENVIRONMENT

RUN set -ex && \
    apk --no-cache add

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libzip-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    curl-dev \
    icu-dev \
    g++ \
    npm \
    mysql-client \
    zip

RUN apk add nodejs
```

When I run docker-compose up -d --build  it is taking recent node version

Answer (score 2):

I think can download Node.js v14.17.6 from NodeSource Node.js binaries using curl.  
so, you can update your Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

ARG SERVER_ENVIRONMENT

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    libzip-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    curl-dev \
    icu-dev \
    g++ \
    npm \
    mysql-client \
    zip \
    bash \
    curl

# Add Node.js v14.17.6 or other 14.x version
RUN curl -sL https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

# Others Dockerfile command，COPY、WORKDIR
```

Comment: Why use the unofficial builds and not the official ones from https://nodejs.org/dist/ ?

Comment: @Mureinik The Node.js version in the Alpine Package Manager (apk) is not always up-to-date and may not contain all versions, especially older ones. Additionally, his official Node.js binaries do not provide builds for the musl library, which is used on Alpine Linux instead of the more common glibc. So using these unofficial builds is a workaround for getting a specific her Node.js version on Alpine Linux.

Comment: @MWY
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

Comment: The URL in the curl command has changed. This works as of this writing: `RUN curl -sL https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=`